# Would there be MITM attack even fix the heartbleed vulnerability?

Tags: certificates, man-in-the-middle, heartbleed

I have read this post [askbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444702/how-to-patch-the-heartbleed-bug-cve-2014-0160-in-openssl), the step to fix the heartbleed vulnerability almost:

1. upgrade openssl.
2. generate new keys.
3. revoke the old certificates.

Some posts say attackers may have got your server's private keys.
If there's the possibility attackers can use your old certificates and private keys do MITM attack?

I'm not clear about web browser's certificates verification. Maybe someone can give a more clear explanation.
this post [Understanding Certificate Revocation Checks](https://web.archive.org/web/20151024153302/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/04/07/enabling-certificate-revocation-check-failure-warnings-in-internet-explorer.aspx?Redirected=true), it seems some web browsers default do not do server certificate revocation.

Comment: Thanks @scuzzy-delta .    I find this related discussion on Hacker News.[Chrome/Firefox aren't checking CA revocation lists](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7556909).  It seems there's more things to do but heartbleed patch.

Answer (score 3):

I *think* I understand the question as:

> If a servers' private keys have been compromised, won't a MITM attack
>   be possible even if the heartbleed vulnerability has been patched?
>   (given that not all browsers mandate Certificate Revocation List (CRL)
>   checking?)

And I believe the answer is indeed **yes**.

Patching against the heartbleed vulnerability prevents any further disclosure of server memory contents. Generating new keys is a precaution in case the old keys did leak. Revoking the old keys by means of adding them to the CRL is a public notification the the old keys are no longer valid.

However, as you've noted, not all browsers thoroughly check CRLs by default. The text below is summarized from a [Netcraft article](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2013/05/13/how-certificate-revocation-doesnt-work-in-practice.html) published by Robert Duncan on 13th May 2013 so may no longer be *entirely* accurate):

> Firefox does not download CRLs for websites which use the most popular
>   types of SSL certificate (all types of certificate except EV which is
>   usually displayed with a green bar)...even if OCSP were available, by
>   default Firefox will only check the validity of the server's
>   certificate and not attempt to check the entire chain of certificates
>   (again, except for EV certificates).
>
> Neither Google Chrome on Android nor Safari on iOS present a warning
>   to the user even after being reset. Safari on iOS does not make
>   revocation checks at all except for Extended Validation certificates
>   and did not make requests for the CRL which would have triggered the
>   revocation error message.
>
> Google Chrome, by default, does not make standard revocation checks
>   for non-EV certificates...
>
> Microsoft's web browser, Internet Explorer is one of the most secure
>   browsers in this context. It fetches revocation information (with a
>   preference for OCSP, but will fallback to CRLs) for the server's
>   certificate and the rest of the certificate chain...
>
> Along with Internet Explorer, Opera is secure by default: it prevents
>   access to the webpage. Opera checks the entirety of the certificate
>   chain using either OCSP or CRLs where appropriate.

Therefore it would be correct (I think) to conclude that the risk of MITM attacks against TLS connections has significantly increased. From the linked article, a good way to protect against such attacks would be to **use IE or Opera when visiting important websites**.